ESP8266 NodeMCU ESP relay control problem
I'm running into a problem trying to control a relay with ESP8266. The relay works I can manually apply power and hear it click when it turns on/off. I'm taking one of the digital outputs to control the relay, D2. It goes through a resistor then to an NPN transistor which outputs about 5 volts when D2 is high. This does not work as I do not hear the relay clicking every few seconds. As I said I know the relay works because I can manually toggle it and I hear the click each time. I only have problems when I run it. 5v should be enough toggle the relay but it doesnt. Any idea what might be happening?
The relay is JQ3-3F(T73) 3VDC, 125VAC, 28 VDC.

Photo of the breadboard. The dark blue jumper goes to ground. The yellow one goes to the relay. I can connect that yellow jumper directly to a voltage source and I can hear it click.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1R2fO95T7AgHR1iimw6O0vhWhFQEc4B79/view?usp=drive_link

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
//Download all required header filers from circuitdigest.com 

//#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

//#include "DNSServer.h"  

//#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>


const byte        DNS_PORT = 53;          // 53 is set as DNS port

IPAddress         apIP(10, 10, 10, 1);    // Network Server

//DNSServer         dnsServer;              // DNS server object

//ESP8266WebServer  webServer(80);          // Webserver object 



int GPIO_2 = 2; //Pin defanition - Relay will be connected to GPIO-0


/*START OF HMTL CODE*/

String style_detials =  //This String defines the style attributes for webpage

"<style type=\"text/css\">"

" body{"

"  background-color: #a69695;"

"}"

"button{"

 " display: inline-block;"

"}"

"#buttons{"

 " text-align: center;"

"}"


".controllButtons{"

 " margin-top: 15px;"

  "margin-left: 5px;"

  "background-color: white;"

  "padding: 10px;"

  "border:1px solid black;"

  "border-radius: 10px;"

  "cursor: pointer;"

  "font-size: 14px;"

"}"


".controllButtons:hover{"

 " background-color: orange;"

  "padding: 10px;"

  "border:1px solid black;"

  "border-radius: 10px;"

  "cursor: pointer;"

  "font-size: 14px;"

"}"


"@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {"

 " button{"

  "  display: block;"

  "}"

  "#buttons{"

   " margin-top: 10%;"

    "margin-left: 35%;"

  "}"

   " .controllButtons{"

    "  margin-top: 15px;"

    "margin-left: 5px;"

    "background-color: white;"

    "padding: 15px;"

    "border:1px solid black;"

    "border-radius: 10px;"

    "cursor: pointer;"

    "font-size: 16px;"

  "}"


  ".controllButtons:hover{"

   " background-color: orange;"

    "padding: 15px;"

    "border:1px solid black;"

    "border-radius: 10px;"

    "cursor: pointer;"

    "font-size: 16px;"

  "}"

"}"

"</style>";


String Home_Screen = "" //Page 1 - Home Screen HTML code

                  "<!DOCTYPE html><html>"

                  "<head><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\">"

                  + style_detials +

                  "<div id=\"buttons\">"

                  "<a style=\"text-decoration:none;\" href=\"relay_ON\"> <button id=\"switchLight1\" class=\"controllButtons\">Turn ON</button> </a>"

                  "<a style=\"text-decoration:none;\" href=\"relay_OFF\"><button id=\"switchLight2\" class=\"controllButtons\">Turn OFF</button>  </a>"

                  "</div>"

                  "<body><h1>Welcome - CircuitDigest</h1>"

                  "</body></html>";


String ON_Screen = "" //Page 2 - If device is turned ON

                  "<!DOCTYPE html><html>"

                  "<head><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\">"

                  + style_detials +

                  "<div id=\"buttons\">"

                  "<a style=\"text-decoration:none;\" href=\"relay_ON\"> <button id=\"switchLight1\" class=\"controllButtons\">Turn ON</button> </a>"

                  "<a style=\"text-decoration:none;\" href=\"relay_OFF\"><button id=\"switchLight2\" class=\"controllButtons\">Turn OFF</button>  </a>"

                  "</div>"

                  "<body><h1>Smart Plug - Turned ON</h1>"

                  "</body></html>";


String OFF_Screen = "" //Page 3 - If device is turned OFF

                  "<!DOCTYPE html><html>"

                  "<head><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\">"

                  + style_detials +

                  "<div id=\"buttons\">"

                  "<a style=\"text-decoration:none;\" href=\"relay_ON\"> <button id=\"switchLight1\" class=\"controllButtons\">Turn ON</button> </a>"

                  "<a style=\"text-decoration:none;\" href=\"relay_OFF\"><button id=\"switchLight2\" class=\"controllButtons\">Turn OFF</button>  </a>"

                  "</div>"

                  "<body><h1>Smart Plug - Turned OFF</h1>"

                  "</body></html>";

                  

/*END OF HMTL CODE*/                    

                  



void setup() {

//   pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT); //LED pin as output for indication 

//   pinMode(GPIO_2, OUTPUT); //GPIO pin as output for Relay control 



//   WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP); //Set ESP in AP mode

//   WiFi.softAPConfig(apIP, apIP, IPAddress(255, 255, 255, 0));

//   WiFi.softAP("ESP_Smart_Plug"); // Name your AP network 


//   dnsServer.start(DNS_PORT, "*", apIP);


//   webServer.onNotFound([]() {

//     webServer.sendHeader("Location", String("http://www.circuitdigest-automation.com/home.html"), true); //Open Home screen by default 

//     webServer.send ( 302, "text/plain", "");

//   });



//   webServer.on("/home.html", []() {

//     webServer.send(200, "text/html", Home_Screen);

//   });



// //ON_Screen

//   webServer.on("/relay_ON", [](){ //If turn on Button is pressed 

//        digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW); //Turn off LED

//        digitalWrite(GPIO_2, HIGH);  //Turn off Relay 

//        webServer.send(200, "text/html", ON_Screen); //Display this screen 

//   });



// //OFF_Screen

//   webServer.on("/relay_OFF", [](){ //If turn off Button is pressed 

//        digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH); //Turn on LED

//        digitalWrite(GPIO_2, LOW); //Turn on Relay 

//        webServer.send(200, "text/html", OFF_Screen); //Display this screen

//   });

//   webServer.begin();

    pinMode(D2, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {

//   dnsServer.processNextRequest();

//   webServer.handleClient();

    digitalWrite(D2, LOW);
    delay(3000);

    digitalWrite(D2, HIGH);
    delay(3000);
}


The point you are testing (the collector of the transistor) should be less than a volt when D2 is asserted high. Are you actually using a 2N3904 and have you double checked that it is connected properly?  Also, if you do not put a flyback diode across the relay coil, you will damage the transistor.

The transistor part number is not correct. I just added it, first time using this code feature. Yes I placed my + of the multimeter on the jumper that is attached to the relay on the relay side so I know its getting the voltage. If I take that same jumper and put it in the + of the breadboard I hear it click. Just not sure why its not now.

Ok what transistor are you using and how is it connected?  Show us a picture of the breadboard.  Generally these problems boil down to using a PNP transistor when you need a NPN or connecting a NPN transistor backwards, possibly because you are referencing a pinout for a different variant e.g. 2N2222 vs. P2N2222.

Its 2N3904. Not sure how it actually ended up being the correct number..

I updated the question with a pic of the breadboard.

I tried using an Arduino board with WIFI and I can get the relay to open/close when I tie the relay pin directly to the Arduino 5v output. But I get the same problem, no relay clicking when I tie GPIO2 directly to the relay bypassing the transistor and resistor
